# Creating an array of array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

***Objective***

To create an array of an array of structs, the dimensions based on a file. Then store that into a Linked List.

I am reading from a file formatted like this:

Read a file that is in the form:

```
name (string)  country (string)  age (int)
john           USA               54
Sam            Aus               18
ect
```

I dont know how many rows and columns the file will have , nor do I know what varible type each column will be

So in theory the first array of struct will contain [NUMBER OF COLUMNS] strucs that will store each variable (using a void pointer and typecasting) along the line( so strucArrayCol[0] = john , structArrayCol[1] = USA ect).

Each of these array of strucs will be stored into another array of strucs which will have [NUMBER OF ROWS] elements so strucArray2Row[0] = strucArrayCol (which contains john , USA  and 54)  and strucArrayRow[1] will contain another strucArrayCol which contains (sam Aus 18).

So right now I can read the file, and find the number or rows, columns and the variable type of each column.

This is where i start having trouble as im not sure how to go about

```
1. How to create this array within array ( I know i need to use Malloc)
2.How I would store the variables in the first array of struc, if I
  wanted to store age could I just do

    void *data = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *((int*)data) = TEMP_AGE;
```

void data being a struc in StrucArrayCol ( in the case of the example if I     wanted to store the age of John void* data would be in StrucArrayCol[3] which is inside StucArrayRow[0], as its the 3rd col in the first line)

Sorry if this dosent make sense
Thanks

Comment: If you don't know the prototype for the struct like (there is always a name, country, age) there is no need to use a struct at all. You could just do a one dimensional array of each column because they have the same type. and then create a new array that contains the addresses to every array.

Comment: Sorry im not great at explaining , the issue is that I wont know what each column will be and also I have to put it in a "Generic Linked List" so I thought this would be the best way to deal with unknown types of variables

Comment: Yeah but why use structs when you can parse the data type of each coloum you can use an array of this data type. A struct would be useful if all list would have the same variables in it (maybe in different order but the name/type don't change) then you could use a struct and fill it with the parsed values of the list got to the next struct in the array and to the next row in the list and do it again.

Comment: So question is do you know the types of the struct members beforehand or not? Lets say does it always have two strings and one int or does this change everytime?

Comment: It will change every time, thats why Im making an array of struc ( each with a void pointer so you can typecast based on the type ) to hold each element along a line, and another array of struc to hold the first strucs

Comment: Why do you want to use a struct? A struct would only work if you know what members should go into that struct. You don't need a struct just for a string.

Comment: so once a file could be   name (string)  country (string)  age (int) and another time it can be year (int) dob (int) address (string)

Comment: Am I able to type cast an array based on what variable type each column is?

Comment: you can create a pointer and allocate memory depending on what you parse from the file and then read the data in. A struct needs a declaration and that can't be changed (afaik). You would need a program that generates to code for your struct in your actual program. I am no pro here but there seems no feasible way to do this to get a linked list... I assume that every row should be one element in this list or should it be just one cell per list element?

Comment: one row is one element in the list

Comment: okay as the rows have no defined members so can't the struct. As even the number of rows have no limit I would say this is a very bad objective and not feasible to do. If there are some limitations on the number of rows it would be possible with a lot of pointer voodoo I guess... The organization of the data in arrays is not that hard. But getting it into structs for a linked list is damn near impossible at least to my knowledge.

Comment: Well I have an idea. If you organize your data in arrays (see answer below), you could use structs instead of the string/int which contain the data type to store and a pointer and you could point to the struct in the next array. This way you could navigate horizontally through your data. And the initial Struct also holds a pointer to the next row element so you could naviagte vertically.

Comment: Hmm ok i'll have a go at doing that thanks

Comment: Okay I made a mistake in my thoughts for the answer a linked list would be possible, if you design your `add` function right. You dont need the array in the end but you need a linked list for your data (and I guess you need `void` pointers because you don't know the next type of data). But it should be possible. By iterating through the arrays of the data an generating linked list of it. So you need a linked list (for the rows) which contains a linked list (for the coloumns). Very big over head here but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a linked-list within a linked-list, assuming there is aversion to anything which is not a linked-list! Declare two linked-list node structures, one for rows in the file, and one for columns within each row:

```
struct column
{
    char *buf;
    struct column *next;
};

struct row
{
    struct column *head;
    struct row *next;
};
```

Read the file one line at a time, add one `row` node for each line. Each row will have its own link-lists, it will parse the line in to columns.

```
struct column* column_create(struct column* cursor, char *line)
{
    struct column *node = malloc(sizeof(struct column));
    node->next = 0;
    node->buf = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
    strcpy(node->buf, line);
    if (cursor)
        cursor->next = node;
    return node;
}

struct row* row_create(struct row* cursor, char *line)
{
    struct row *node = malloc(sizeof(struct row));
    node->next = 0;
    node->head = 0;

    //parse the line in to columns
    struct column *col = 0;
    char *token = strtok(line, " \n");
    while (token)
    {
        col = column_create(col, token);
        if (!node->head)
            node->head = col;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    if (cursor)
        cursor->next = node;
    return node;
}
```

---

Or you can do this with a 2-dimensional array of text (which would be 3-dimensional array of characters). Or use an array of strings to hold all the lines in the file, then parse each line in to column. From there, you can test each column to see if it is integer or not.

If you don't know the number of lines in the file, use `realloc` to allocate as much memory is needed during run time. This example reads all the lines in file, and copies it to an array of lines:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char **lines = 0;
    int lines_size = 0;
    int lines_capacity = 0;
    char buf[1024];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f))
    {
        int len = strlen(buf);
        if (!len) continue;
        if (lines_size == lines_capacity)
        {
            lines_capacity += 16;
            lines = realloc(lines, lines_capacity * sizeof(char*));
        }

        lines[lines_size] = malloc(len + 1);
        strcpy(lines[lines_size], buf);
        lines_size++;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lines_size; i++)
        printf("%s", lines[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < lines_size; i++)
        free(lines[i]);
    free(lines);
    return 0;
}
```

This will work as long as line length in the file never exceeds `1024`. Separately, you can parse each line using `strtok`

```
void parseline(char *line)
{
    char copy[1024];
    strcpy(copy, line);
    char *token = strtok(copy, " \n");
    while (token)
    {
        printf("[%s], ", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @KamiKaze The asker mentions arrays in another section. I should have asked if this is for homework with specific linked list requirements. Linked lists are complicated to work with and slow compared to vector-style memory management.

Comment: yes it is my bad, thats why im so hell bent on using a linked list

Comment: Still regardless thankyou for the suggestion of the 2D array it should be useful

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It is also not really usefull to do this with a linked list, but I guess getting the arrays straight is the first part of it and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a linked list in a linked list.
Barmak wrote how to get the data. So here is how to get the linked list.

```
struct sString{ 
char* str;
void* next_hor;
void* next_ver;
};
struct sInt{ 
char* Int;
void* next_hor;
void* next_ver;
};

in first column
if ( check  type of column)
    {for each row
      {
       generate corresponding struct and link it to previous element (add-function) 

      }
    }
for other columns
{
  ( check  type of column)
    {for each row
      {
       generate corresponding struct and link it to previous element (add-function) 
       also iterate though linked list and insert the horizontal link

      }
    }
}
```

Its very clustered, has tons of overhead and is hard to manage but it should work.

The vertical pointer could also be of the right type as the types don't change in a column.